# Does the commercial helicopter training in 61.129(c)(3)(i) require a CFII?

Tags: faa-regulations, helicopter, flight-training

For the commercial ticket in a helicopter you need 5 hours of hood time. Can any CFI provide this training or does it require a CFII?

[14 CFR 61.129(c)(3)(i)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=54114e3c8b9c19d21c0737ce8a77f4a3&node=se14.2.61_1129&rgn=div8):

> Five hours on the control and maneuvering of a helicopter solely by
>   reference to instruments using a view-limiting device including
>   attitude instrument flying, partial panel skills, recovery from
>   unusual flight attitudes, and intercepting and tracking navigational
>   systems. This aeronautical experience may be performed in an aircraft,
>   full flight simulator, flight training device, or an aviation training
>   device;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CFI can give the training because it's training "solely by reference to instruments". If it were "instrument training", you would need a CFII.

See [the Jablecki (2016) interpretation](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/data/interps/2016/jablecki%20-%20(2016)%20legal%20interpretation.pdf), which addresses your specific question:

> In order to provide instrument training for a commercial pilot
>   certificate or ATP certificate, a flight instructor must have an
>   instrument rating on his or her flight instructor certificate.
>   However, §61.129(c)(3)(i), unlike its counterparts in §61.129,
>   does not have a requirement for "instrument training" as defined in 14
>   CFR §61.1. Instead, §61.129(c)(3)(i) requires training on the
>   "control and maneuvering of a helicopter solely by reference to
>   instruments." Therefore, the training in §61.129(c)(3)(i) is not
>   considered "instrument training" that requires a certified flight
>   instructor to have an instrument rating on his or her flight
>   instructor certificate.

Comment: Thanks a million. As a follow up, any idea of the equipment requirements for this training?

Comment: By the way, is there a tool for searching the faa legal interpretations?

Comment: @JohnHutchinson I'm not sure what you mean by "equipment requirements". The regulation just says what the training exercises should be. You might want to ask a new question if you need more information. As for searching the legal interpretations, I use Google :-) The FAA's own search engine is terrible.

Comment: thanks! I mean what are the minimum instruments needed. Do you need a VOR, a CDI, etc. I’ll do some research before asking a new question